# Numeric Virtual keypad on sencha touch 2 on a search field

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to get a numeric virtual keypad on mobile device when i start typing in search field of sencha touch2 application. By default i get an alphabet virtual keypad . I want numeric keypad to appear, as i am searching for numbers in the search field. Could anyone help me on this.

---

Sorry for not being specific.I want the search field to be searchable with both numbers and alphabets, but since in my case the user searches more for numbers, i want the number keypad to pop instead of default alphabet keypad.

Comment: You have to change it to Ext.field.Numberfield

Comment: I agree, it would b nice to have a config tht allow that (numeric keyboar) but still be a searchfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Ext.field.Numberfield](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Number)